# Data Explorer refuses to believe I'm a person

Tags: bug, data-explorer, captcha

I tried to run a simple SEDE query a minute ago, while not logged in, and was of course told I had to prove I was human. Except that as you  can see, I wasn't given any ability to prove it

[image: SEDE failing at CAPTCHA]

Clicking the "I'm a Human Being" button in vain just popped up "Error: looks like you typed in the wrong words - try again".

So. I've done some web development, I know how to do some early diagnosis, see if it's something on my end; I'll pop open the browser's developer tools, and see if any files are failing to load. Unfortunately, once I opened the developer tools and refreshed the page, I saw this:

[image: SEDE having a bad day]

It then changed the moment I clicked anything.

[image: SEDE continuing to have a bad day]

I then (wisely) decided to close the developer tools, and instead bypass the Humanity check by logging in, which worked. But SEDE still seems to need a bit of fixing.

<sub>For the record: IE11, Win7, no extensions, no userscripts; AFAIK the only thing non-standard on this browser is that I leave it always zoomed in, and unzooming didn't help.</sub>

Comment: This is *exactly* what a robot would say. ;)

Comment: I can't reproduce either issue with the same setup, I'm afraid.

Comment: What's [this from](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NgVbW.png) in your screenshot?

Comment: @TimStone It's the button used to filter out various forms of active content (flash and the like). And it's grey rather than blue, indicating it's off. First thing I checked.

Comment: Hm...Well the problem just seems to be that some resources didn't load for you, but I'm not sure why that would have happened.

Comment: @TimStone Yeah, I can't repro any more now, so I guess I'll chalk it up to the usual Caching somewhere between SE and here. Thanks anyway.